# How can I add a join to this bulky SQL union statement?

Tags: mysql, join, union, relational-database, inner-join

I have a statement that ranks items based on number of shared tags and speakers based on linking tables, but I want it to also be able to pull the talk_title and talk_brief info from the main tbl_talks which isn't actually in the query right now (just the linking tables are used).
basically the linking tables have talk_id and tag_id or talk_id and speaker_id.

I tried a few ways of trying to LEFT JOIN, or adding tbl_talks inside the paired SELECTs that the union is applied to but had no luck.  I need to associate both the tbl_linking_talk_tag.talk_id and tbl_linking_speakers_talk with tbl_talks.talk_id and with that, grab talk_title and talk_brief from tbl_talks

```
SELECT talk_id, count(*) AS common_term_count FROM 
      (
      SELECT talk_id FROM tbl_linking_talk_tag WHERE tag_id IN 
         (SELECT tag_id FROM tbl_linking_talk_tag WHERE talk_id = 1)
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT talk_id FROM tbl_linking_speakers_talk WHERE speaker_id IN
         (SELECT speaker_id FROM tbl_linking_speakers_talk WHERE talk_id = 1)
       ) AS accumulator_table

 WHERE talk_id != 1 

 GROUP BY talk_id

 ORDER BY common_term_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this code:

```
 SELECT a.talk_id, a.talk_image, a.talk_title, a.talk_brief, count(b.talk_id)  AS common_term_count 
        FROM tbl_talks a LEFT OUTER JOIN
             (
             SELECT talk_id FROM tbl_linking_talk_tag WHERE tag_id IN 
                (SELECT tag_id FROM tbl_linking_talk_tag WHERE talk_id = 1)
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT talk_id FROM tbl_linking_speakers_talk WHERE speaker_id IN
                (SELECT speaker_id FROM tbl_linking_speakers_talk WHERE talk_id = 1) 
             ) AS b
             ON a.talk_id = b.talk_id       
        WHERE a.talk_id != 1        
        GROUP BY b.talk_id      
        ORDER BY common_term_count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you need a union in this case. If all you need is count then why not try something like..

SELECT talk_id, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_linking_talk_tag sub WHERE tag_id IN 
 (SELECT tag_id FROM tbl_linking_talk_tag WHERE talk_id = 1) and maintalk.talk_id=sub.talk_id) +
(SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_linking_speakers_talk sub1 WHERE speaker_id IN
         (SELECT speaker_id FROM tbl_linking_speakers_talk WHERE talk_id = 1) and and maintalk.talk_id=sub1.talk_id
       ),talk_title,talk_brief 
from maintalk
where talk_id != 1
group by talk_id

The syntax may need some fixing but the approach is

select columns,  from maintable